# Stuck on moving to SDcard

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, external-sd, sd-card

I have Alcatel 5054D with Lollipop (5.1.1) on board. I tried to move some apps to SDcard by pressing "Move to SDcard". Some of these apps moved successfully and some stuck in "Moving" state. I tried to reinstall these stuck apps, but they still show "Moving" instead of "Move to SDcard/telephone". I do not understand if they still in the phone memory or on the card. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing **cache** and **reboot** your phone.
If still the problem presist, try 3rd party apps available on playstore like link2sd,move2sd and more.

Comment: Clearing cache and rebooting doesn't work. Furthermore the phone is not rooted to use link2sd.

Comment: I think link2sd works even without root.. But uses the system method..